# How to find which Stored Procedure has some text We're searching for?

Tags: stored-procedures

I just know few words which are there in some Stored Procedure already written..
How can I find that Procedure in SQL ?

Comment: What RDBMS? Oracle, MySQL, SQL-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple sql query like given below - SQL Server

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%\<Your content here >\%\'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can find the text of stored procedures in `USER_SOURCE`

e.g.

```
select * from user_source where text like `%FOOBAR%`;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT routine_schema, routine_name
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routine_body LIKE '%word%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple alternative way’s with which we can correctly find all the Stored Procedure’s having a given text

1. SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id),        OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)FROM sys.proceduresWHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%SearchString%'